# Chrome Calculating CSS Dimensions too specifically

Tags: css, google-chrome, dimensions

Has anyone ever seen this before, Chrome is calculating my values, even in the body too specifically. Meaning the values are in the millionths if not billions decimals places:

Example:
width: 281.6477355957031px;

I do not have this problem with IE. I normally wouldn't care, but these fractional pixels are really screwing up an effort to add a sticky header to a common grid control we've developed  to work with OData.

This issues seems to happen when just a body tag is on the form with no other lower level controls. I am baffled.

Does anyone know of a way to reset the entire html page or even better, just reset a particular element so that every element beneath it calculates using whole or near whole values?

thanks!

EDIT
Just to be clear, I have taken everything off the page except the main container, with no styles and Chrome is calculating this parent html tag, with a value of 1508.1817626953125px. This element has no styles attached

Comment: How does this screw up your page? Please show the code you're using, and explain how it's messed up by more precise measurements.

Comment: @Barmar I guess : 281.6477355957031px; will be on screen 282 when you request 281 ? So it jumps a pixel , where others do not.

Comment: @GCyrillus, yes, when trying to put a static header on a table, the values are always off because these fractional values make the width value jump 1 pixel

Comment: try to write those values in CSS like this : 279.6px up to 279.9px to see when you get 280 in Chrome like everywhere else :) at screen pixels are not fractionnable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my open question, the cause is Visual Studio 2012. Since I was using localhost to run my site, some plug-in or setting is set to force chrome that specifies dimensions much more specific than any normal human would want. Upon not using machine name instead of localhost the dimensions are back to normal. If i find the exact setting, i will report back later.

EDIT:

Upon further discovery, its not VS, its my browser zooming. At certain zooming in Chrome pixels in the development console are calculated to a sub pixel level. I imagine due to some inner division calculation. This throws off my calculations for allowing the a staic table header at different zoom levels. I will be forced to deal with CSS pixel rounding in my own calculation to handle these.